# Bind_param() error on null

Tags: php

Here My Code

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){

    $this->_error = false;

    if ($this->_query === $this->_conn->prepare($sql)) {
        $x=1;
        if (count($params)) {
            /* @var $param type */
            foreach ($params as $param)
            { /* bind parameters for markers */
                $this->_query->bind_param($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }    /* execute query */
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);// Fetch all
            $this->_count = $this->_query->num_rows();// Free result set
        }
        else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }

    }
    return $this; 
}
```

favorite
When I run my code I get the following error:

Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null 
I googled for this problem for few hours now and I cant figure out where the problem is. I know this subject is posted to many times but I'm php beginner and I don't see why this is not working.

Comment: `$this->_query` is null. Where do you set it?

Comment: if ($this->_query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql))  not ===   if ($this->_query === $this->_conn->prepare($sql))

Comment: Isn't the first argument to `bind_param()` suppose to be a string defining the data type(s) and not an integer? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: thanks for rep all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `assignment operator` `=` instead of `comparison operator` `===`

```
if ($this->_query = $this->_conn->prepare($sql))
```

Not `===`

```
if ($this->_query === $this->_conn->prepare($sql))
```

Comment: glad to help you :)  @Jason